# empty tags in XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

```
<Person>
  <id>12</id>
  <Fname>Phil</Fname>
  <Lname></Lname>
  //or
  <id>13</id>
  <Fname>Phil</Fname>
  <Lname>0</Lname>
</Person>
```

I am generating XML from sql server 2005 using xml path('Person')

Here in this xml structure instead of

`<Lname></Lname>` or `<Lname>0</Lname>` I need as `<Lname/>`

Comment: please give more details in which library and language your are using.

Comment: From the XML point of view `<Lname></Lname>` and `<Lname/>` are both empty tags and are equivalent. So I wouldn't be surprised if there was no way to specify how the database should create empty tags.

Comment: select * from table_name for xml path('Person')

Comment: @Bharath: You do know that there exist multiple DBMS? *Which one* are you using?

Comment: also you could simply write a small sql-to-xml function yourself, if you only want to create xml from persons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the XML datatype, empty tags in converted to a [EmptyElemTag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-empty). Using `for xml` directly does however not do that.

To get the result you want you can use your query as a sub-query in a field list of another `for xml path` query.

```
select (
       select id,
              Fname,
              Lname
       from Person
       for xml path('Person'), type
       )
for xml path('')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e50b/5)

Comment: insert into Person values (13, 'Phil', NULL);

Comment: when there was a null value in column instead of 0 or '', this concept doesnt work. Do I need to go back and use ISNULL concept in all columns

Comment: @Bharath What output do you want when the value is `null`?

Comment: @Bharath If you want the empty tag then yes, `isnull(Lname, '') as Lname`.